# Doing inference using pytorch saved weights in .tar file using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, pytorch

I am doing a machine learning project where I need to display the predictions on a webpage. The webpage is build using Django. I have predictions function and the weights of the model but how to integrate the predictions function, model, and weights in the Django code and do predictions.

My prediction code

```
def predicting(model, device, loader):
    model.eval()
    total_preds = torch.Tensor()
    total_labels = torch.Tensor()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for solute_graphs, solvent_graphs, solute_lens, solvent_lens in loader:
            outputs, i_map = model(
            [solute_graphs.to(device), solvent_graphs.to(device), torch.tensor(solute_lens).to(device),
             torch.tensor(solvent_lens).to(device)])   
            print(outputs)
            total_preds = torch.cat((total_preds, outputs.cpu()), 0)
    return total_preds.numpy().flatten()
```

I have saved the weights in `.tar` file so I need to run the model while loading the weights for prediction. I have no idea where to keep my PyTorch model and the weights to do inference using Django. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy a PyTorch deep learning classifier at Heroku using Django in 30 minutes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLk2We1rJPs

Using PyTorch Inside a Django App:

https://stefanbschneider.github.io/blog/pytorch-django

I hope this will help you get started!!!